# Why is the inferred type like this ？

Tags: typescript

example

```
function Component<TProperty, TData extends (prop: TProperty) => Record<string, any>, TComputed extends { [k: string]: (data: TProperty & (TData extends ((prop: any) => infer R) ? R : never)) => any }>
(opt: { properties: TProperty, data: TData, computed: TComputed })
: TData { return '' as any }

const test1 = Component({
    properties: { propA: '' },
    data: () => { return { dataA: '' } }, 
    computed: {
        ccc(AllData) {                         // this AllData of type  is  {propA:string} & {dataA: string}                  
            return AllData.propA  
        }
    }
})

const test2 = Component({
    properties: { propA: ''},
    data: (prop) => { return { dataA: '' } }, // Add parameters "prop"     In order to be usable  {dataX:prop.xxx}
    computed: {
        ccc(AllData) {                      // this Alldata of type  is {propA:string} & Record<string, any>      why???
            return AllData.propA
        }
    }
})
```

[playground]https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-qQ5QTKbYuEyYl3Tqo0N9QmRSFYnHm-Honhx+5khNoIWW4TuXCcKicbAXejiABEkNrPIAkuhDMIKvBkGgAEYENCQUScbssvvYwkADVkkJt-FnzvpVN2wmGjoZTKtHK5Ru3-SL8DF4ithOlsqYCtKPlV+s1KV0+jbJjMGpsdm0PIA7iLGFUf6v6Wa8UtSVbQRVd536N1DjAEAgA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for a canonical answer, especially [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872#issuecomment-651450956).  In the `test2` example, you are essentially asking the compiler to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters `TProperty`, `TData`, and `TComputed` and [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the types of the callback parameters in the `data` and `computed` properties.  Such inference happens in a limited number of phases where first the compiler plugs in wildcard/default values for some of the unknown types to infer others, and then it uses those inferences to inform the next round.  Unfortunately, it is unable to infer all the types you need before it stops, and so some of the type positions still have their default values (like `Record<string, any>`, the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) for the return type of `TData`).

In cases like this, you usually have to give up some inference in favor of some manually specified or annotated types.  In your `test1` example, the `data` callback parameter is missing and therefore no longer contextually typed.  If you want something like `test2` to succeed, you can free the compiler from contextually typing the parameter by annotating it explicitly:

```
const test3 = Component({
    properties: { propA: '' },
    data: (prop: { propA: string }) => { return { dataA: '' } },
    computed: {
        ccc(AllData) {                      
            return AllData.propA
        }
    }
})
```

And if you inspect that, you'll see that `AllData` has type `{ propA: string; } & { dataA: string; }` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aACAwsgtgB1QKbTwA8oaFaACgDTmUAiaBAHvEQCYDOaAFLgCdkuAFzUAlGgC8APjQAlArGQCOJLvAGJoAcxpoAhtACeMuiEqZmbTjwDeaANoBrMRq26AumN4cD8AzEqNAAyPiZWdmhuPn4hUUMTSVk0bXACAQVJAH4FNDFoAgA3DPFkuSNjNABfUBleYXgxB0FhDKQCLiD9PwCxBn1lPEh2DjEMGvF6Cn60BwECeEgBdAByVcMeSprQUGVoDTR2DQBGaUwcfELiXjtptFbcdsRO5of4gEExdZrzS17AnxynM0AslisQQCvmgftVfvchrgRgQxnN7pZYJjeB8ADY4hj+AySByWUlk8kUAD0lKOAAtEFs8QSAmhkOAjsYnhQGRQ7I8vu5tDo4WE7FC3JohXCKTL0eSwct0Lj8YSAHT8uUUWoWSja6pTMAgfaHY7wABM5yweEINzuOooj2erxB-O+G2qf0oAJ8j2B80WishhOhsN+aGpaA+HA4DwMAgM2EWGR4ACJHinSQBJdAqDgZI7INAAIwIaEgXAMRZxpbmAIAGiJHqqWC3tRjLsjUXaKZjYNimYTiTLh5QI-B6TxlQDWez4Jyazy+Z8RILdCKFEpc+pJbp9JU5KSAO604zZM+a0kKiHK5kGdWfC9t3WgfW7I2oE2deAAZktlxt8C3PcjoCB0XQusuMLup6FDenwjxvK6aCrjokzSHI-rgugDjilBNRhhGUYxrgcYJkmAipumWY5qo+bwIWJZlhWVY1mKhINk2LYsE+FCIp2zQXr2-YqgEQ4jsOY4TpGeLTmyHJcqk9iuih65sQE0IqRelhXkqA4BPewgfI+9x6gaoBAA)

Comment: I would have expected [ms/TS#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) to improve this but so far it doesn't look like it.  